# Email Footer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, footer

Trying to change the footer in my transactional Emails from admin interface in Magento 2.

First I click **Marketing** then, **Email Templates** then, I **add new template** then, I choose footer, then I name the template and subject, then I add content and finally save.

I then go to stores configuration then sales then sales Emails and I can choose what I saved but then if I choose my footer I won't be able to choose the actual Email...it's either one or the other.

Ok, then I go back to the marketing section and say I'll just change the existing footer file.

I almost can do this but it makes me save a new file name so I can't just save...you would think I could just change the footer and press save without changing the file name...the footer "supports" the main email along with header...

Answer (score 5):

I realize it's been months since you asked this, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this post and wonders the same thing, I figured it out.  The email templates are one thing, the transactional email config is another, and the header and footer used on those emails is a 3rd thing, and they're all stored in different places (thanks, Magento)

### Email Templates

When you first visit **Marketing -> Email Templates** you'll be confused because there's nothing there.  This is because Magento defaults to using html files in the codebase, but it will use your configured templates from Admin if they exist.  To create one, simply click **New Template** at the top.  You can load the existing template to use as a starting point, edit, and save.

### Email Header/Footer

These are also considered *templates* and can be edited/created under **Marketing -> Email Templates** just like the actual *Transactional Email* template.  However, there's no way to tell Magento you want to use it under this screen.  For that, we need to visit a different section

- Navigate to **Content ->** Design -> **Configuration**
- Pick the config you wish to edit
- At the bottom, expand **Transactional Emails**

Here you can set the template used for the *Header* and *Footer* for all emails

### Transaction Email Type -> Template Config

Finally, you have to tell Magento what template to use for any given transactional email. For this, navigate to **Stores -> Configuration**, expand the **Sales** section, and choose **Sales Emails**.  Here you can choose the template you created for a particular email type (i.e. New Order for Guest).

Comment: Adobe Commerce Supporting Documentation: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/systems/communications/email-template-custom.html?lang=en#footer-template